# Flutter Page Navigation : Back Button to have same behaviour as Back Arrow of the AppBar

Tags: flutter, navigation, back-button

I'm just starting with flutter. I found a nice example on the internet of an app. It's about navigation between widgets.

article: https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386

full code: https://gist.github.com/HansMuller/b189642d10fd236a41044fdf7626f7b0

the **lib folder** of my implementation of the app: https://github.com/Liam-Noah/myapp_navigation

my question is this:
How can I get the back button to have the same behaviour as the back arrow of the Appbar. The latter just returns to the previous screen. The backbutton exits the app entirely.

what I managed to do:
add WillPopScope at the root of the tree widget of HomePage:

```dart
WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: (){
          //return Navigator.of(context).maybePop<bool>(false);

        Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/");

          return Future.value(false);
        },
```

results:
this works, but returns to the first tab of the bottomNavigationBar even if you have others selected. It still doesn't behave like the back arrow of the AppBar.

I tried replacing with in the onWillPop callback:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).maybePop<bool>(false);
```

but with no success, it results in an endless loop. Even though the appbar actually calls this function.

Thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

or

```
  Navigator.pop(context);
```